# If I have given a design as a gift, do they now own the copyright?

Tags: copyright, legal, licensing

I had worked on a series of designs for my friend's birthday. After giving them to him he asked about the legal consequences of using them. I hadn't thought about it and don't intend to want anything in return, but I was wondering what would happen in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per **U.S. Copyright law** the *moment* a piece of art is created the artist owns the copyright - be it painting, design, writing, sculpture, etc. Other countries have other laws... The [Digital Millennium Copyright Act](https://www.dmca.com/) is *supposed* to protect artwork over international borders... but, well, some countries also ignore that.

**If you wish to allow your friend to merely use your artwork, without restriction, you really don't need to do anything.**

---

Copyright infringement is only perusable if the copyright holder wishes to pursue it. It's not like there's a league of "Copyright cops" anywhere. Copyright infringement is a *civil* issue, not a *criminal statute*. Which means.. Courts and money ... not jail and handcuffs.

The media - meaning movie studios, television companies, production houses, etc. - have done a good job of *miseducating* the general public into *thinking* copyright infringement is a criminal matter. It is not.

---

If you own the copyright... you can give it to your friend outright so *they* then legally own the work. They can then go and resell it for millions! `:)`

Or you can retain the copyright and simply never pursue any action.

*Legally*, if you wish to prevent your friend from reusing or reselling anything, you need to retain the copyright and your friend should sign an agreement stating you own the work and are merely *licensing* the design to your friend. It can not be resold, repurposed, etc.

If *your friend* wants legal protection to use the design however they wish, then they need to get *you* to sign an agreement stating you are relinquishing all rights to the work.

---

Search for "copyright" here and checkout other similar questions, like [**this one**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54181/copyright-on-free-work?noredirect=1&lq=1) or just peruse the "related" links on the right side of this page (on a computer, not mobile).